# tensorflow Error encountered when trying to serialize two NN

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training two Neural Networks simultaneously. When I try to store them I'm getting the following error:

> tensorflow - WARNING - Error encountered when serializing
>   data_preprocessing. Type is unsupported, or the types of the items
>   don't match field type in CollectionDef. 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'name'

both networks have their own class, Below is some simplified code with only one Network class. I just want to show that i create two Networks with tflearn with the same tf.Session. when Im trying to save them in the training process I'm getting the error above

```
class Network:
    def create_network(self):
        inputs = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, self.s_dim])
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(inputs, 400, activation='relu',bias=True)
        out = tflearn.fully_connected(net, self.a_dim, activation='tanh')
        return inputs, out

    def init(self,sess):
        ...
        self.inputs, self.out = self.create_network()
        self.loss = tflearn.mean_square(self.placeholder, self.out)
        self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
        ...

class Main:
        with tf.Session() as sess:
                    network1=NN.Network(sess)
                    network2=NN.Network(sess)
                    self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
                    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
                    for i in range(steps):
                               train(network1,network2,sess)
                               self.saver.save(self.sess,'name',i)
```

btw: I'm using Cuda 8, cudnn 5 and tensorflow rc 0.11.0

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong without debugging the issue a bit further. Based on the error message, I would guess a `None` value has made its way into a CollectionDef that Tensorflow is trying to save. I suspect the problem is in code you haven't shown, in the tflearn library, or in Tensorflow itself. If you can produce a small, self-contained, reproducible example, the developers of tflearn or Tensorflow might be able to help you.